# Prove the limit of $a_n = n(x^{1/n} - 1)$ defined to be $f(x)$ , has the following properties; $f(1)=0, f(x)>0$ if $x >0$ and $f(x)<0$ if $0<x<1$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

> Show that if $\lim(n(x^{1/n} - 1) = f(x)$,
> then $f(1)=0$,and $f(x)>0$ if $x>1,f(x)<0$ if $0<x<1$.

```
 I proved that f(1)=0 by mere substitution. To show f(x)>0 we suppose x>1 which implies that n(x^(1/n) - 1)>0.
Let a_n:= n(x^(1/n) - 1). Then Lim a_n=f(x)>0 or Lim a_n=f(x)=0.

 The main problem is to show that f(x)≠0 for x>1. This also showed up in the x<1 case. How do I tackle it from here?
```

Comment: Please use MathJac to render the math Thank you

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Let $g_x(t)=x^t=e^{t\log(x)}$.

The sequence $a_n(x)$ in the OP approximates the derivative of $g_x$ at $t=0$ for fixed $x$.

$$
g_x’(0)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{x^h-1}{h}=\log(x)
$$